# Magento2: Tax rates issue

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation

**TAX ZONE AND RATES**

I have set 0% for active union vat and 19% for non-active union vat
https://prnt.sc/ssiam3

TAX RULES:
here I add a rule:
https://prnt.sc/ssibau

Now I create customer group:
Wholesaler Active Union VAT and here I assigned tax classes Active Union VAT 0%:
https://prnt.sc/ssibpr

Now I created a new user and assign it to this group with VAT 0%.

Now when I try to place order still Magento add tax 19%
https://prnt.sc/ssickm

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

**Here we debug and provide solution:**

Example:  when we set in `stores --> configuration ---> Automatic assign to customer group`. (And here when we select example automatic assign to group with 19% VAT), 
then even if we change the group directly in the customer edition it won't work.

When ordering, the system will always catch the group we selected during automatic assignment. (To check this we can try create an order directly in customer account from back-end)

**To solve this issue, you need to turn off completely the automatic group membership.**